# How to search issues/pr whose author is NOT somebody in github?

Tags: github

I want to filter all issues created by robot like:
`is:issue is:open author:not:robot`

How to get all issues except those created by robot?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

use dash - to exclude:
-author:robot

Comment: Amazing. Works like charm. Is this a new feature?

Comment: hmm seems to be broken as of May 2021 :-/

Comment: Effing genius you are!

Answer (score 19):

So I tried the same to search for issues / PRs which are not by dependabot.

Unfortunately there is not "not bot" filter :(

But you can add to the Issues / PullRequests filters `-author:app/dependabot` which will exclude the given author.

Unfortunately again, it does not support multiple authors as it seems, so if you want to exclude multiple bots or for example on a repository where dependabot-preview is used, you must use the global search in the top left of GitHub and simply add your search query there and select `search in this repository` - or use advanced search: https://github.com/search/advanced.

`is:open is:pr -author:app/dependabot -author:app/dependabot-preview`

> Replace `is:pr` with `is:issue` if you are looking for issues

**Direct link, simply add the repo:**

https://github.com/search/advanced?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Apr+-author%3Aapp%2Fdependabot+-author%3Aapp%2Fdependabot-preview&type=Issues)

Comment: This is what I was looking for, as the intuitive `-author:dependabot` does not work.